# Help catalytic converter

Tags: honda, accord, catalytic-converter, part-interchange

Hi I have a 2005 Honda Accord 2.4l I need a cat for it to pass smog I found a 2009 Honda Accord v6 with a cat for sell would that fit my Honda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be a direct fit? No. They are two completely different converters. Could you *make it fit*? Anything is possible if you have the welding skills. Take a look at these two images. The first is the one for your engine. The second is one of the ones for the 2009 V6:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So if I was to get it welded on you think it will pass smog or no?